# bug or feature: open and io.open are not interchangeable

Tags: python, api, file-io

I always thought `open` and `io.open` were interchangeable.
Apparently not, if I believe this snippet:

```
import ctypes, io

class POINT(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("x", ctypes.c_int),("y", ctypes.c_int)]
# THIS WORKS
with open("mypoints.bin", "wb") as f: 
    for i in range(10):
        p = POINT(i,10-i)
        print p.x, p.y
        f.write(p)
# THIS FAILS 
with io.open("mypoints.bin", "wb") as f:
    for i in range(10):
        p = POINT(i,10-i)
        print p.x, p.y
        f.write(p)

0 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    f.write(p)
  File "c:\Python26\lib\io.py", line 1070, in write
    self._write_buf.extend(b)
TypeError: 'POINT' object is not iterable
```

Note: I tested in Python 2.6.6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's a "bug", `io.open` in Python 2.6 is slightly broken. It was supposed to be work like 3.x's `open` to ease transition, but it doesn't work correctly in some cases. For example, it doesn't support objects with the buffer interface like in your case. This is fixed in Python 2.7 where the builtin `open` can be used like the `open` in 3.x, and `io.open` is just an alias to it.

If you need binary mode, use `open`, it behaves the same in 2.x and 3.x, with the only difference being that in 2.x it accepts for writing objects that it shouldn't (such as `unicode` objects). If you need text mode, use `codecs.open` or `io.open` with `encoding` argument. Both are available in 3.x.

But note that `open` and `io.open` were meant to not be interchangeable, because `io` is Python 3's `io` module, and in Python 3 `open` is very different from the `open` in Python 2.6 or less.

http://docs.python.org/library/io.html